# How to upgrade Amazon Kinesis Analytics Apache Flink runtime?

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming, amazon-kinesis-analytics

We have an application running on Apache Flink 1.13, presume we have a branch we have updated the code to Flink 1.15.2 and built a jar and put that on S3.

What do we do in the AWS Console to change an existing KDA "Streaming application"'s Flink version so that we can Configure it to use our new jar?

Comment: Have you checked [AWS Kinesis Updating a Stream](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/updating-a-stream.html)?

Comment: Ta, couldn't see anything regarding upgrading Flink version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the AWS Doc

> You cannot update the RuntimeEnvironment of an existing application. If you need to update an application's RuntimeEnvironment, you must delete the application and create it again.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/managed-flink/latest/apiv2/API_UpdateApplication.html